# What is the best way to get the size of text in bytes in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, byte, java-11

I have implemented a cryptographic algorithm in Java. Now, I want to measure the size of the message before and after encryption in bytes.

How to get the size of the text in bytes?

For example, if I have a simple text `Hi! I am alphanumeric (8÷4=2)`

I have tried my best but can't find a good solution.

```
String temp = "Hi! I am alphanumeric (8÷4=2)"
temp.length() // this works because in ASCII every char takes one byte

// and in java every char in String takes two bytes so multiply by 2
temp.length() * 2

// also String.getBytes().length and getBytes("UTF-8").length
// returns same result
```

But in my case after decryption of message the chars becomes the mixture of ASCII and Unicode.

e.g. `QÂʫP†ǒ!‡˜q‡Úy¦\dƒὥì£‰ὥ`

Upper methods returns the `length` or `length * 2`

But I want to calculate the actual bytes (not in JVM). For example the char `a` takes one byte in general and Unicode `™` for example takes two bytes.

So how to implement this technique in Java?

I want some this likes the technique used in this website http://bytesizematters.com/

It gives me `26 bytes` for this text `QÂʫP†ǒ!‡˜q‡Úy¦\dƒὥì£‰ὥ` although the length of text is 22.

Comment: It gives me one bytes for every char (ASCII or Unicode). e.g. I check 'new String("ЖЖ").getBytes().length`. It gives me 2 answer. Although it should give me 4 because these are Unicode and of 2 byte (each char)

Comment: "But i want to calculate the actual bytes" problem is that amount of bytes depends on encoding. "*For example the char `a` takes one byte in general and Unicode*" this not always true. In UTF-16 characters are represented by either two bytes or four bytes (surrogate pairs). Java internally stores characters using UTF-16, but when you use `getBytes()` it returns bytes which use OS default encoding (which most likely is UTF-8). So if you want to know how many bytes text need, you need to specify encoding.

Comment: I want to be in general. e.g all the char which ASCII supports return 1 byte. The chars which can be shown in two bytes return 2. and so on.

Comment: Are you thinks if http://bytesizematters.com/ give correct bytes. I want to implement some this like this. Any idea!

Comment: "I want bytes as a general" but **there is no *general* encoding**. Some are more popular but there are no general ones. Anyway what you describe looks like [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). First 128  characters (in range from U+0000 to U+007F) will be written using 1 byte in form `0xxxxxxx`; range U+0080 U+07FF is written using `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx` form; U+0800 U+FFFF using `1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware: `String` is for Unicode text (being able to mix all kind of scripts) and `char` is two bytes UTF-16.

This means that binary data `byte[]` need to know its encoding/charset, and will be converted to String.

```
byte[] b = ...
String s = ...
b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
s = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Without explicit charset of the bytes, the platform default is taken, which will give non-portable code.

`UTF-8` will allow all text, not just some scripts, but Greek, Arab, Japanese.

However as there is a conversion involved, non-text binary data can get corrupted, will not be legal UTF-8, will cost double the memory and be slower because of the conversion.

*Hence avoid String for binary data at all costs.*

To respond to your question:

- You might get away by `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` - which is a single byte encoding.
- `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).length()` will then correspond to `String.length()` though the String might use double the memory as `char` is two bytes.

Alternatives to String:

- `byte[]` themselves, `Arrays` provides utility functions, like `arrayEquals`.
- `ByteArrayInputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream`
- `ByteBuffer` can wrap `byte[]`; can read and write short/int/...
- Convert the `byte[]` to a **Base64** String using `Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes)`.

---

***Converting a byte to some char***

The goal is to convert a byte to a visible symbol displayable in a GUI text field, and where the length in chars is the same as the number of original bytes.

For instance the font **Lucida Sans Unicode** has from U+2400 symbols representing the ASCII control characters. For the bytes with an 8th bit, one could take Cyrillic, though confusion may arise because of similarity Cyrillic `е` and Latin `e`.

```
static char byte2char(byte b) {
    if (b < 0) { // -128 .. -1
        return (char)(0x400 - b);
    } else if (b < 32) {
        return (char)(0x2400 + b);
    } else if (b == 127) {
        return '\u25C1';
    } else {
        return (char) b;
    }
}
```

A `char` is a UTF-16 encoding of Unicode, but here also correspond to a Unicode code point (int).

A byte is signed, hence ranges from -128 to 127.

Comment: Actually i am using JavaFX. By using text field the user types (only ASCII chars) after the encryption the text is converted to ASCII and Unicode and i want to calculate byte exact the same way as this http://bytesizematters.com/ uses my algorithm works correctly and fast i only need to get size!!!

Comment: Okay. A group of bytes could give different Strings depending on the assumed charset the bytes are in. With cryptographic encoding, there is no charset. Use "ISO-8859-1" which will count an 'ü' as 1. Decoding is a bit unreliable, but the count most likely correct.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood. Before the text is encrypted, Getting the UTF-8 bytes is (1) complete, (2) statistically most compact for text with latin-1 (ASCII) like HTML pages. After encryption you have binary data, a `byte[]`, so you can take a .length.

Comment: Sorry! I  can't understand you. But as i know, In encryption of text I only allow user to use ASCII only (256) and convert char to binary using Integer.toBinaryString(char) and maps controls chars to Unicode and during decoding maps in reverse order. My problem is it want to get bytes as mini-mum bytes e.g for ASCII 1 bytes and for UTF-8 2 bytes.

Comment: No! After encryption i again convert message to chars (ASCII and Unicode). Means get only ASCII and converts it to mixture of ASCII and Unicode) because controls chars can't be represented so i convert these to Unicode.

Comment: Show the code to receive that (convert to ASCII respectively Unicode). It can be someone else has a better answer.

Comment: Ok! Actually when i encrypt message then i convert every char to binary form using `Integer.toBinaryString(char)`. Then drop some bits and try remaining bits to char again (by checking if it is not control char (ASCII (0-31 & 127)) then simple convert it to char using `(char) Integer.parseInt(bits, 2)` else maps bits to some Unicode char e.g. `00` -> `ж`. And during decryption simply check if not unicode ? then get standard binary else get binary against in mapping....

Comment: This means that `String.length() = char[].length`. But some, admittedly very specific, chars (like Arab script) will get mutilated; `char` = 2 bytes, `byte` = 1 byte. I would not do the juggling to chars.

Comment: But in simple i want that if any char can be represented as 8 bits then it must be of one byte other wise 2 bytes.... As show in this web these are one byte https://www.ascii-code.com/ other maybe two are four???

Comment: @user10606381 and how does the decoder know whether you used one, two, or whatever number of bytes?

Comment: I have created such a function to display a byte as char.

Comment: Firstly thanks for you in trust to solve my problem!
Decoder simple checks if char in present in mapping then get binary from mapping else get standard ASCII binary. AS:
`if (map.containsKey(String.valueOf(c))) {
 var m = map.get(String.valueOf(c));
 var charAsBinary = Integer.parseInt(m);
} else {
 var charAsBinary = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(c));
}`

Comment: @user10606381 so you’re not really decoding but remembering the original. The actual meaning of decoding and encoding is to perform conversions which can be reversed without magic.